# Calling repaint for specific JPanel in JFrame repaints also JDialog

Tags: java, swing, lwjgl, repaint

Below is a small example for what i describe

Well, I have a simple `JFrame` with a `JPanel` as its `contentPane` that i `repaint` with a `SwingWorker` every 20 ms with `panel.repaint()`.

Also, I have a `JDialog` opened that shows its own graphics with opengl (I use a `AWTGLCanvas` from `LWJGL` library) that swaps buffers and `repaint()` every time it does paint its content (faster than the 20ms).

The big problem is that in some way repainting my `JPanel` also affects the `JDialog` meaning that if i remove the `panel.repaint()` (which i have done) it works fine!  When i have the `panel.repaint()` the `JDialog` shows some strange lines like i have cut the graphics in 2 and try to move them together with no success. I dont know if they call it flicker but it may be that problem.

```
public testFrame(){
    panel = new JPanel(){
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
             //do the painting for the JPanel here
        }
    }
    setContentPane(panel);
    updateTime();
}

 public void updateTime(){
      SwingWorker worker = new SWingWorker(){
          @Override
      protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
             while(stopTimer == false){
               Thread.sleep(20);
               if(isFocused() == true){
                 timer += 0.2f;
                 panel.repaint();   
               }        
             }
             return null;
          }
      };
      worker.execute();
 }
```

And here is my `AWTGLCanvas.paint` method in my `JDialog contentPane`

```
@Override
public void paintGL() {
    //do some painting with classic opengl
    swapBuffers(); //awtglcanvas built-in method, meaning i cant control it
    repaint(); // it actually runs paintGL() again
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could be a heavy/light weight component issue

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: You can try to define a custom clip shape to exclude JDialog's position

Comment: fixed it!I put my problem in brackets to be more comprehensive

Comment: @StanislavL : I tried to panel.repaint(myRectangleHere); but same problem exists for some really weird reason

Comment: Do i interrupt the gui thread with repainting at two different frequencies?;

Comment: @MadProgrammer : It says that you can use LWJGL in Swing, but since Swing uses light-weight components, the LWJGL view will appear on top of any Swing components (like a menu that drops down over top of a LWJGL view will not show up). Should that be my problem here?

Comment: Mixing heavy and lightweight components can be problematic and they can fight for z-ordering when painted.  It's possible that the `JDialog`'s `JRootPane` and `contentPane` are been updated periodically and interfering with the LWJGL canvas as they are using different painting approaches

Comment: Yes, but why that happens only when i repaint a JPanel that doesnt even belong to JDialog

Comment: @PeGiannOS JPanel painting doesn't use OpenGL (Most likely Qt / GDI+ etc) That means JVM talks to OS talking to Graphics card. OpenGL talks to the Graphics card (driver) directly. This is probably the cause of the issue.

Comment: @AlexR Is there a way to fix this or suggest me a way to do it for example without the AWTGLCanvas?.Or is there a way to suspend or say synchronize Java Graphics way with the direct opengl way?I mean what if i called to repaint my JPanel through Opengl graphics?Thanx in advance :)

Comment: @PeGiannOS Though one there. I would use LWJGL in a Display window and not as a component.

Comment: @AlexR I will try to simulate my problem with the Display window and see if it works.Thanks for the help.

Comment: @AlexR Well, i did show a Display with all the graphics working but the same problem occurs (strange lines like flicker i describe).The only big advantage of this way is that i got a 20%-25% less CPU usage.Thank you for that.

Comment: @PeGiannOS Well, that's at least something. Just in case this might be relevant, what is your CPU / GPU? (Might be completely off, but I suspect a weak graphics card / CPU might influence experience)

Comment: @AlexR I have intel core i5 2410M CPU - for GPU i have AMD graphics card ,it says radeon graphics (i dont have nvidia for best results i know)

Comment: @PeGiannOS Hmmm.. CPU is average but GPU might be the problem. Have you tried combining JavaFX with OpenGL yet? Swing is no longer developed.

Comment: @AlexR Well, i dont think i will make any good by changing the whole system i am working with all my gui projects so far by learning JavaFx so my next step is to dive deeper to opengl and learn how to make this project 100% with Opengl 2d stuff (Swing made sound it so simple :( ).Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: Did your JPanel create your JDialog?  You said the opposite wasn't true, but that's not what's relevant.  If your JDialog is a child of your JPanel, then calling `repaint()` on your JPanel will call it on your JDialog as well.  If you don't want that, you could probably override `paint()` in your JPanel to **not** call `super.paint()`, but that would cause it not to automatically repaint **any** lightweight components created by that JPanel (source: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#lw), so make sure that's what you'd want...

Comment: I think @Tim is right. How exactly do you create the `JDialog`? Try using this constructor `JDialog(Window owner)`, setting the `JFrame` as the owner.

Comment: @chhh Ι tried to use the constructor JDialog(myJFrame) and the approach of overriding paint(Graphics g) without using super.paint(g),(which i didnt use also before in the paintComponent method that may be my problem of understanding well what Tim says) and nothing works :(.

Comment: @PeGiannOS another thing - in your paintGL() you call repaint(), which, as you say, call paintGL() again. So your timer is not working at all, it just runs paintGL() as fast as it can, and from time to time you interfere with your SwingWorker, which calls repaint(). Maybe just removing repaint() from paintGL() will help?

Comment: @PeGiannOS and what Tim says is simple - override paint() method, in which don't call super.paint() as the first line, because by default paint() calls the following, in order: 1) paintComponent() 2) paintBorder() 3) paintChildren(). You want to not trigger paintChildren() all the time (you want, but not all of them). Read this article: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html